# implementation problems with xor cipher

Tags: implementation, xor

I tried to reimplement the simple Xor cipher in the book `Applied Cryptography
Protocols, Algorithms, and Source Code in C A book by Bruce Schneier` using python. The code can be found in section 1.4 of the book.

### c code form the book

```
/* Usage:  crypto key input_file output_file */ 
void main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
     FILE *fi, *fo; 
     char *cp; 
     int c; 
     if ((cp = argv[1]) && *cp!='\0')  { 
         if ((fi = fopen(argv[2], "rb")) != NULL)  { 
             if ((fo = fopen(argv[3], "wb")) != NULL)  { 
                  while ((c = getc(fi)) != EOF)  { 
                       if (!*cp) cp = argv[1]; 
                       c ^= *(cp++); 
                       putc(c,fo); 
                  } 
                  fclose(fo); 
             } 
             fclose(fi); 
         } 
     } 
}
```

### my python version

```
import sys
def main(argc, argv):
    fi = open(argv[2], 'rb')
    fo = open(argv[3], 'wb')
    index = 0

    while True:
        x = fi.read(1)
        if not x: break
        x = ord(x.decode())
        fo.write( chr(x^ord( argv[1][index] )).encode() ) 
        index += 1 
        if index == len(argv): index = 0
    fi.close()
    fo.close()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # usage: python3.7 simple_xor.py <key> <inputfile> <outputfile>
    main( len(sys.argv), sys.argv )
```

They both work well. **BUT**, given the same **plaintext(inputfile)** and the same **key** to both codes above they don't return the same **ciphertext**.

However they both decrypt their respective ciphertexts well. (meaning into the same plaintext)

My question is: Why are they not generating the same ciphertext, given the same key and plaintext??

Comment: I added a small change to your code and it produces the same cypher text, feel free to check out my answer below, i hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C version XORs individual *bytes* with the key. The Python version uses `encode()` and `decode()` that works on *characters*, not *bytes*. Try with accented characters or emojis instead of ASCII characters to see the difference.

Furthermore, the condition to wrap the `index` down to `0` is wrong; you are not comparing it with the length of the key.

That being said, this question is more about how to use Python than cryptography.

Comment: ‘accented’, or is this a kind of sforzando markup for text?

Comment: minor mistake: "_The C version XORs individual bytes with the key._"  `c^=*(cp++);`  Here `c` is an `int` while `*(cp++)` is a `char`. But since `char`s are 1 byte integers(int) in C, we are xorring 4 bytes(since `int` is 4 bytes) with another 4 bytes ( 3 bytes of zeros followed by 1 byte of the char).

Comment: _"Furthermore, the condition to wrap the index down to 0 is wrong; you are not comparing it with the length of the key."_ absolutely correct!!

Comment: Instead of this: `if index == len(argv): index = 0`. It should have been `if index == len(argv[1]): index = 0`

Comment: _" The Python version uses encode() and decode() that works on characters, not bytes."_ To make it work on bytes, replace `x = ord(x.decode())` -> `x = int(x.hex(),16)`. Since the bytes may not be encoded in utf-8. And also replace `fo.write( chr(x^ord( argv[1][index] )).encode() ) ` with `fo.write(  bytes([x^ord( argv[1][index])]) )`.

Answer (score 0):

I made very small changes and ran it against the C version and this seems to work as you'd like:

I added a key assignment to argv[1] and changed #ord(x.decode()) to int(x.hex(),16).

I unencrypted the cypher text from the c code and the cypher text seems the same as the one generated by python and the output was correct. I used:

```
cat cypher.txt
Cypher

./a.out key cypher.txt cypher.out
./crypt.py key cypher.out cypher.txt.test
```

Cypher text is the same:

```
$ ./a.out key cypher.txt cypher.out
$cat cypher.out 
(   
        a

$ ./crypt.py key cypher.txt cypher2.out
$ cat cypher2.out 
(   
        a
```

And the updated python code:

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python3
import sys
def main(argc, argv):
    key=argv[1]
    fi = open(argv[2], 'rb')
    fo = open(argv[3], 'wb')
    index = 0

    while True:
        x = fi.read(1)
        if not x: break
        x = ord(x.decode()) #int(x.hex(),16) 
        fo.write( chr(x^ord( key[index] )).encode() ) 
        index += 1 
        if index == len(key): index = 0
    fi.close()
    fo.close()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # usage: python3.7 simple_xor.py <key> <inputfile> <outputfile>
    main( len(sys.argv), sys.argv )
```

Comment: Why: x = int(x.hex(),16) #ord(x.decode()). They both generate the same value. Don't they?

Comment: Your right, i think what was happening is that your key may have been long, as the the key wasn't encoding right when i was debugging. This one works though right?

Comment: side note: if you wanted to check that `cypher.out` and `cypher2.out` are equal or the same, use `sha256sum` if you are on linux. command `$ sha256sum cypher.out cypher2.out`. Instead of using `cat`.